# Robot running off Raspberry Pi A+

Tags: usb, hardware, power, software-development

I am participating in a competition where I need to make a motorized vehicle that goes a distance you learn immediately before competing. What I have in mind is to mount a Rasp Pi A+ and a motor to a lightweight aluminium chassis or whatever would work best. My goal isn't as much speed as it is effectiveness. The track is 9 - 12 meters long. I'm hoping I can just write a formula for the amount of time the motor runs will be close to how far it travels.

Power constraints for the motor:

> The vehicle may use no more than 6 individual cells (labeled 1.5 volts or less each), a single 9-volt battery, or a single battery pack (labeled 7.2 bolts or less) at any given time during the 8 minutes. Batteries need not be installed until immediately prior to the run. Only electrical energy stored in these batteries may be used to propel the vehicle.

I can use a separate power source for the Rasp Pi. What would be the best way of going about all of this?

Comment: Isn't this a regular competition?  Why not look at last years entries?

Comment: @joan I'm at the high school level. The previous competitions were at the middle school level. As far as I've been able to check nobody has done one on this scale so to say and I'm looking to go all in.This is the most accurate way that I know to stop it at any distance I want. Thanks

Comment: An Arduino-type platform would be much more suited to, reliable, and easy to work with for the described task.  In contrast the pi has a lengthy and fragile boot process each time you change the battery.  The pi only makes sense if you need something like vision or complicated algorithms or storage or USB peripherals which are hard for a simple MCU.  Use wheel encoders, not a timer.

Comment: Given the cell count limitation you may want a 3.3v mini Arduino or else use 6 fresh alkaline AA if you have to contend with regulator dropout on a 5v board.